# How To Insert and Update Data From Same Form using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, crud

Can Anyone Help me to write Controller,Model and View From Which There Would Be a Single form(View) That takes the Hidden Id and Controller Checks whether The Request From View have id or not and depending upon that it would insert and update the same.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html go through the tutorial and you should be able to understand how that process works...

Comment: Actually i have used many edit update and add but not for the same form so i have used guide but not getting @sintakonte

Comment: What have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just have to check if the hidden id exists in your database or not. If it doesn't then you `insert`, if it does you `update`. Generally this is how you do it:

```
<?php

class some_controller extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Submits the form
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function submit_form() {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $data = array(
            'somedata' => $this->input->post('somedata'),
            'someotherdata' => $this->input->post('someotherdata')
        );
        $this->load->model('some_model');
        if (!is_null($id) && $this->some_model->id_exists($id)) {
            return $this->db->update('sometable', array('id' => $id), $data);
        } else {
            // assumes sometable autoincrements id
            // otherwise $data = array_merge(array('id' => $id), $data);
            return $this->db->insert('sometable', $data);
        }
    }

}

class some_model extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Checks if id exists in sometable
     * 
     * @return boolean TRUE if item with $id exists in sometable
     */
    public function id_exists($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('sometable') > 0;
    }

}
```

Please note: good practice would call for moving the insert and update (in fact all queries) *into a model*. This is just an example.

Comment: How to show the input name if we already have the details with respect to that id. when we edit @Alex

Comment: Hey there, do you mean how do you populate the input fields if you already have those details? You could do for every field `isset($_POST['field_name']) ? $_POST['field_name'] : $row->field_name` so if the field name is present from `$_POST` data you show that otherwise you show the `$field_name` from the database. This requires you to get the fields from the database before loading the page. But that would only be something you want to do if you are sure it's an update!

Comment: Thanx i forgot about ternary operation @Alex